# flask server on raspberry pi stopped responding

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, cron, raspbian

I set up a flask server on my raspberry pi and set up a crontab to start the server on reboot. It was working fine for a while, for the past couple of days it stopped responding even after I rebooted the pi.

It seems like that the server is running because when I ssh in and try to run another server it says that the address is already in use.

Any ideas why my server is not responding anymore?

also, this may or may not be related but when I typed crontab -e I got the following error: 
/tmp/crontab.Qqy98c: No space left on device
Creation of temporary crontab file failed - aborting

Comment: Your file system is full. Free some space! This is BTW off topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

`Address is already in use` error indicates that some process is occupying the host/port that your Flask application is trying to use.

To resolve this problem, find out which processes are running on that port, then kill them. For example, if you use the default setting of port 5000, you can do the following in the terminal:

```
lsof -i:5000
```

This will show you the process that's running on port 5000 -- Take note of the process id. Let's say it's `12345` for example.

```
kill 12345
```

This should free up the address, allowing the Flask application to launch normally.

The error `No space left on device Creation of temporary crontab file failed` should be somewhat self-explanatory. If you're running so low on file space, you should strongly consider clearing up space. Otherwise, you're bound to run into all kinds of problems.